# Change view visibility for each item inside a RecyclerView within a Fragment when a text is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, visibility

I've got A Fragment which contains a Layout header with an exit button, a title text  and an edit text which is clickable.

Below the header layout I have a RecyclerView that matches the parent layout in width and height.

[image]

Each row of the RecyclerView has an ImageView, a title text, a description text,  a price text and an invisible ImageView used to remove the item from the Recycler.

[image]

Because my EDIT TextView is declared in the Fragment I can't get the ViewHolder inside the adapter in order to change the ImageView visibility like this:

[image]

All I want is to make the image visible for each row when the EDIT text is pressed.

Here is the Adapter and ViewHolder code:

```
public class BagItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BagItemsAdapter.BagViewHolder> {

private List<BagItem> mBagList;
private Context mContext;
private String quantityPrefix, pricePrefix;

public BagItemsAdapter(Context context,List<BagItem> list)
{
    this.mBagList = list;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public BagViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bag_shop_item_layout,parent,false);

    return new BagViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BagViewHolder holder, int position) {

    BagItem currentItem = mBagList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentItem.getItemImageUrl()).into(holder.bagItemImage);
    holder.bagItemTitleBrand.setText(currentItem.getItemBrandTitle());
    holder.bagItemDescription.setText(currentItem.getItemDescription());

    holder.removeBagItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mBagList.size();
}

class BagViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    @BindView(R.id.bag_item_image) ImageView bagItemImage;
    @BindView(R.id.remove_bag_item) ImageView removeBagItem;
    @BindView(R.id.bag_item_title_brand) TextView bagItemTitleBrand;
    @BindView(R.id.bag_item_description) TextView bagItemDescription;
    @BindView(R.id.bag_item_quantity) TextView bagItemQuantity;
    @BindView(R.id.bag_item_price) TextView bagItemPrice;
    @BindView(R.id.bag_item_product) TextView bagItemProduct;


    public BagViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
    }
                }
              }
```

The Fragment code:

```
public class BagFragment extends Fragment implements BagView {

@BindView(R.id.bag_items_recycler)RecyclerView mRecycler;
@BindView(R.id.edit_bag_items_text)TextView editBagItems;
@BindView(R.id.exit_bag_image)ImageView exitBagImage;
@BindView(R.id.no_items_in_bag_image)ImageView noItemsImage;
@BindView(R.id.no_items_in_bag_text)TextView noItemsText;
@BindView(R.id.my_bag_title_text)TextView myBagTitleText;
@BindView(R.id.check_out_button)Button checkOutButton;

BagPresenter mPresenter;
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPresenter = new BagPresenter(getActivity(),this);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_bag_fragment_layout,container,false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,v);
    mPresenter.getBagItems();
    return v;
}



@OnClick({R.id.exit_bag_image,R.id.edit_bag_items_text,R.id.check_out_button})
public void onBagViewsClicked(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.exit_bag_image:
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
        case R.id.edit_bag_items_text:
            if(editBagItems.getText().equals(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.edit_string)))
            {
             editBagItems.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.done_string));
                editBagItems.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                //TODO here is where I should make the delete ImageView visible for each item
          ((BagItemsAdapter)mRecycler.getAdapter()).showDeleteImage(); "this does not work because i can't get the ViewHolder from the adapter"
            }else if(editBagItems.getText().equals(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.done_string)))
            {
                editBagItems.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.edit_string));
                editBagItems.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                //TODO here is where I should hide the delete ImageView
              ((BagItemsAdapter)mRecycler.getAdapter()).hideDeleteImage(); "this does not work"
            }


            }
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please provide your Adapter and ViewHolder code.

Comment: also provide your fragment class code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add a new property to your `BagItem`. We'll called it `editMode`.

```
class BagItem {
    boolean editMode;
}
```

Initially `editMode` is false. When the user push edit button, you need to change `editMode` to true. Make sure that your `mBagList` is set to public. Next you need to notify the recycler view adapter that the data was changed.

```
for (BagItem bagItem: bagItemsAdapter.mBagList) {
    bagItem.editMode = true;
}
bagItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You also need to update the visibility of `removeBagItem` according to `editMode` value.

```
holder.removeBagItem.setVisibility(currentItem.editMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first you make one boolean global variable in adapter class for example.

   ```
   private boolean isVisible = false;
   ```
2. According to that variable set visibility of imageview in onBindViewHolder say for example

   ```
   if(isVisible){
     holder.removeBagItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }else{
     holder.removeBagItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   ```
3. Create on public method which set visibility of imageView in adapter for example

   ```
   public void setVisibility(){
     isVisible = true;
     this.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```
4. from fragment edit text click call that adapter method for example.

   ```
   adapter.setVisibility();
   ```